# Eloquent or SQL way on how to check if child table has certain multiple values

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

What is the Eloquent or SQL way of checking if a table has a value based on the ID given?

Sample customer's table:

```
id   name    created_at
1   test_1   01/01/2019
2   test_2   01/24/2019
3   test_3   01/25/2019
```

Sample purchases table:

```
id   customer_id   status      created_at
1         2        paid        02/01/2019
2         2        paid        02/02/2019
3         2        unpaid      02/03/2019
4         2        cancelled   02/03/2019
5         3        paid        02/03/2019
6         1        paid        02/03/2019
```

what I want to achieve is to check if there's a customer with unpaid and cancelled status

currently my code is like this:

```
Customers::with('purchases')->get();
```

but I want it to only get the customers with unpaid and cancelled status from purchases table

Comment: Please clarify if you need last status or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by doing

```
doesntHave()
```

of Laravel Eloquent.

in the customer's model, I have put:

```
public function unpaid_and_cancelled_purchases() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Purchase', 'customer_id', 'id')
               ->whereIn('status', ['unpaid', 'cancelled']);
}
```

in my controller, I have put it like this:

```
$customers = Customers::doesntHave('unpaid_and_cancelled_purchases')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

With SQL you need to `group by customer_id` and the condition `count(distinct status) = 2` in the `having` clause will get you the customers you want:

```
select customer_id
from purchases
where status in ('unpaid', 'cancelled')
group by customer_id
having count(distinct status) = 2
```

If you want customers with only 'unpaid' and 'cancelled' status and no other status:

```
select customer_id
from purchases
group by customer_id
having 
  count(distinct status) = 2
  and 
  sum(case when status not in ('unpaid', 'cancelled') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Smart move with that ‘count(distinct...)’

Answer (score 0):

```
select name
from customers c
inner join purchases p on c.id = p.id
where c.id = CustomerId
and status in (cancelled, unpaid)
group by customer.id
```